# How to use JpaRepository operations (findOne) when having a native query with union all statment

Tags: spring, spring-data-jpa

I need to use JpaRepository with a query that has an union statement inside. Is it possible? This is my current implementation and the error I get so far:

Entity:

```
@Entity
public class PaymentDetails {
  @Id
  @Column
  private String id;
  @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
  @Column(name = "rowtype")
  private PaymentType paymentType;
  @Embedded
  private CardDetails cardDetails;
  @Embedded
  private BankAccountDetails bankAccountDetails;
```

Interface and query:

```
public interface PaymentsRepositoryManagerPayment1 extends JpaRepository<PaymentDetails,String> {
  @Query(value = "select id,'CARD' as rowtype, cardnumber, cardtype, nameoncard, expirydate, startdate, securitycode, semafonecr, issuenumber, "
        + "null accountnumber, null accountholdername, null sortcode, null bic, null iban, null currency from pcs.BsbTempCardDetails "
        + "where id = :id union all select id, 'BANK' as rowtype, null cardnumber, null cardtype, null nameoncard, null expirydate, null startdate, "
        + "null securitycode, null semafonecr, null issuenumber, accountnumber, accountholdername, sortcode, bic, iban, currency "
        + "from pcs.BsbTempBankAccountDetails where id = :id", nativeQuery = true) <br>
List< PaymentDetails > findPaymentDetails(@Param("id") String id);
```

Call:

```
@Autowired private PaymentsRepositoryManagerPayment1 paymentsRepositoryManagerPayment1;
@Transactional(value = "paymentsRepositoryTransactionManager")
public PaymentDetails retrievePaymentDetailsById1(String id) {
  return paymentsRepositoryManagerPayment1.findOne(id);
}
```

ERROR:

> org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not load an entity: [com.bskyb.repository.payments.model.PaymentDetails#cardId]; SQL [select paymentdet0_.id as id2_0_, paymentdet0_.accountholdername as accounth2_2_0_, paymentdet0_.accountnumber as accountn3_2_0_, paymentdet0_.bic as bic2_0_, paymentdet0_.currency as currency2_0_, paymentdet0_.iban as iban2_0_, paymentdet0_.sortcode as sortcode2_0_, paymentdet0_.cardnumber as cardnumber2_0_, paymentdet0_.cardtype as cardtype2_0_, paymentdet0_.expirydate as expirydate2_0_, paymentdet0_.issuenumber as issuenu11_2_0_, paymentdet0_.nameoncard as nameoncard2_0_, paymentdet0_.securitycode as securit13_2_0_, paymentdet0_.startdate as startdate2_0_, paymentdet0_.rowtype as rowtype2_0_ from PaymentDetails paymentdet0_ where paymentdet0_.id=?]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not load an entity: [com.bskyb.repository.payments.model.PaymentDetails#cardId]
>   java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist

Answer (score 1):

All of what you showed doesn't seem to be too related to the exception you see:

1. The exception complaints about a table not being available. Make sure `PaymentDetails` exists when you issue the query (this is probably *the* reason you see the exception).
2. You call `findOne(…)`. Thus the query declaration on `findPaymentDetails(…)` doesn't play into the use case at all.

Comment: I have tried another approach and used TABLE_PER_CLASS inheritance for being able to deal with "union" statement. With this solution it works perfect.